# Command output parsing

Tags: java, python, text-parsing

The OS X command `system_profiler SPAudioDataType` gives the output shown in Appendix 1

This looks very difficult to parse to me.

For example:

- Get the `Connection` of the `Speaker`

`grep` for `^\s+Connection: (.*)$` does not help: capture group `\1` will have the `Connection` value, but also pick up values for lines *not* nested under `Speaker`.

Interestingly, it might be easier to parse with `sed`. e.g. wait to see line Audio, then line Speaker, ..., then regex for the text following `:`.

I could `grep` `MULTILINE` on the whole text and first match `Speaker`, then `Connection`, skipping newlines/blanks.

Is there a library to build an object model of nested nodes from text lines of varying indentation?

Is there a way to query that object model akin to CSS's  selectors? e.g. `Audio > Speaker > Connection > Value`

I like the way YAML considers whitespace, but this does not parse as YAML.

A library in Java or Python would be great to study.

I was coding something on my own, then I decided to ask:

---

```
 def main():
     c = 0
     with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
         for l in (l.rstrip() for l in f):
             m = l.lstrip()
             if not m:
                 continue
             i = len(l) - len(m)
             if i < c:
               pass # Towards parent
             elif i > c:
               pass # A child
             else:
               pass # A sibling
             c = i
```

---

I suspect I need to assume the first node will be at indentation `0` and remember all *seen* indentation levels to be able to reattach a node of *decreasing* indentation compared with the previous level to its parent or as a sibling of higher levels of nesting.

#### Appendix 1

---

```
Audio:

    Intel High Definition Audio:

      Audio ID: 29

        Headphone:

          Connection: Combination Output

        Speaker:

          Connection: Internal

        Line Input:

          Connection: Combination Input

        Internal Microphone:

          Connection: Internal

        S/PDIF Optical Digital Audio Input:

          Connection: Combination Input

        S/PDIF Optical Digital Audio Output:

          Connection: Combination Output

        External Microphone / iPhone Headset:

          Connection: Combination Output

        HDMI / DisplayPort Output:

          Connection: Display

    Devices:

        Built-in Microphone:

          Default Input Device: Yes
          Input Channels: 2
          Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
          Current SampleRate: 44100
          Transport: Built-in

        Built-in Input:

          Input Channels: 2
          Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
          Current SampleRate: 44100
          Transport: Built-in

        Built-in Output:

          Default Output Device: Yes
          Default System Output Device: Yes
          Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
          Output Channels: 2
          Current SampleRate: 44100
          Transport: Built-in
```

---

Comment: Is that not a valid YAML document?

Comment: Does not seem to be: Python `import yaml; yaml.load(open(f).read())` gives `ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here` "Headphone:"

Comment: That's a good point - how am _I_ supposed to parse that line? Is `Audio ID:` an item on it's own, holding `29`, or a subheading for more items? Remove the `29`, and I reckon it'll parse.

Comment: Doesn't work. See my attempt in Python.. could you finish it off with something that creates the object model nesting from the indentation levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coded this for parsing:

```
import sys
import asciitree
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, indent, parent):
        self.name = name
        self.indent = indent
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []
    def add(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
def main():
    current_indent = -1
    root_node = Node('Root', current_indent, None)
    current_node = root_node
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as file_to_parse:
        for scanned_line in (l.rstrip() for l in file_to_parse):
            line_content = scanned_line.lstrip()
            if not line_content:
                continue
            indent = len(scanned_line) - len(line_content)
            while True:
              if indent > current_node.indent:
                  parent = current_node
                  break
              elif indent == current_node.indent:
                  parent = current_node.parent
                  break
              else:
                  current_node = current_node.parent
            child = Node(line_content, indent, parent)
            parent.add(child)
            current_node = child
    print(asciitree.draw_tree(root_node))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

yielding this object model:

```
Root
  +--Audio:
     +--Intel High Definition Audio:
     |  +--Audio ID: 29
     |     +--Headphone:
     |     |  +--Connection: Combination Output
     |     +--Speaker:
     |     |  +--Connection: Internal
     |     +--Line Input:
     |     |  +--Connection: Combination Input
     |     +--Internal Microphone:
     |     |  +--Connection: Internal
     |     +--S/PDIF Optical Digital Audio Input:
     |     |  +--Connection: Combination Input
     |     +--S/PDIF Optical Digital Audio Output:
     |     |  +--Connection: Combination Output
     |     +--External Microphone / iPhone Headset:
     |     |  +--Connection: Combination Output
     |     +--HDMI / DisplayPort Output:
     |        +--Connection: Display
     +--Devices:
        +--Built-in Microphone:
        |  +--Default Input Device: Yes
        |  +--Input Channels: 2
        |  +--Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
        |  +--Current SampleRate: 44100
        |  +--Transport: Built-in
        +--Built-in Input:
        |  +--Input Channels: 2
        |  +--Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
        |  +--Current SampleRate: 44100
        |  +--Transport: Built-in
        +--Built-in Output:
        |  +--Default Output Device: Yes
        |  +--Default System Output Device: Yes
        |  +--Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
        |  +--Output Channels: 2
        |  +--Current SampleRate: 44100
        |  +--Transport: Built-in
        +--After Effects 11.0:
        |  +--Manufacturer: Apple, Inc.
        |  +--Current SampleRate: 0
        |  +--Transport: Unknown
        +--Prelude 1.0:
        |  +--Manufacturer: Apple, Inc.
        |  +--Current SampleRate: 0
        |  +--Transport: Unknown
        +--Premiere Pro 6.0:
           +--Manufacturer: Apple, Inc.
           +--Current SampleRate: 0
           +--Transport: Unknown
```

I need to implement a search function like CSS selectors now..

What do you think? Incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

This is still an "OSX admin" question. Use the [`-xml` flag](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/system_profiler.8.html):

```
system_profiler -xml SPAudioDataType
```

Which outputs a ready-to-parse pList file.

Comment: That is a solution to the problem at hand. Absolutely agree with you. But what about parsing that type of indented text in general?

Comment: @Robottinosino: That's not a general text format at all - it's a specific format that the designers of `system_profiler` was human readable. Unless of course, that's actually a valid yaml document

Comment: Agree, it is unusual indeed. Is there a smart way to build an object model which considers nesting (where nesting relationships are given by indentation) which is coded into a ready-to-use library?

Comment: Can you see my attempt in Python? I got stuck for ideas at "Towards parent". Notice: I am a beginner and would really love some help..